# ReadBinary APDU always returning invalid length (SW1=0x67) [ISO7816]

Tags: smartcard, apdu, iso-7816-4

I try to read a file from a smart card (via PCSC). I can successfully `SELECT` the MF and the desired EF, then I execute a `ReadBinary` APDU, but the result is always SW1=0x67, SW2=0x00 (invalid LE).

I know, that the file is there and that it is valid. I know its size (84bytes) and I know that it is selectable and readable without permissions (ALWAYS).

My understanding is, that I provide 0 to the LE parameter for a full length result, or I provide the effective length (plus 4 bytes for the header), but neither parameters work.

I tinkered a lot with the parametrization without success. The result is always (0x67). My general approach for reading the file after successfully selecting it (0x9000) is as follows:

```
CLA: depending of the logical channel, 0x00 for me
Instruction: 0xB0
P1: 0
P2: 0
LE: 0 or length of the file +4 
Data: empty
IsoCase: Case4Short
```

Can anybody hint me in the right direction, what I’m doing wrong? I'm an absolute beginner, probably I made some silly mistakes.

Here is my command sequence:

```
00-A4-00-00-02-3F-00-00  : 9000
00-A4-00-00-02-2F-06-00  : 9000
00-B0-00-00-00-00        : 6700
```

Comment: Try sending `00-B0-00-00-00` instead of `00-B0-00-00-00-00` (it is cla-ins-p1-p2-le, there is no lc). It should not be Case4Short but Case2Short. Which particular card is it?

Comment: Hi vlp, perfect. Make that comment an answer and I will accept it and grant the bounty to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `00-B0-00-00-00` instead of `00-B0-00-00-00-00` (it is CLA-INS-P1-P2-Le -- there is no extra Lc) as `READ BINARY` is a case 2 command in this case.

Please note that many cards do not conform to ISO-7816-4 and it is always better to refer to the respective card manual.

Good luck with your project!